# simple_html_dom parser file_get_html() is returning nothing no error on large 6 MB Html file

Tags: php, html, dom

I tried file_get_html('file1.html') which is about 5KB works well and i get what i need but when i try this on file_get_html('file2.html') which is about 6 MB it returns nothing..
is there any memory limits or file size limits or limits set by XAMP Defaults?
is there any alternative way of getting file HTML?
I tried

```
include('htmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
echo $string = file_get_html('file1.html');
```

also tried

```
ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
```

with NO luck

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1273830

Comment: tried again with no returns no errors if i give incorrect file name it returns 

Warning: file_get_contents(BAf.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\htmldom\simple_html_dom.php on line 75